# Push notification is not working with iOS9 and above

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I have tried these bellow ways:

1. I noticed was the Device Token gets changed for every fresh install which is kind of weird as we have to update the server for every new instance. Now i have fixed with save UUID in keychains.
2. I have created development provision and check. But not getting any luck.
3. I have created Adhoc provision and check. But still not getting PN.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how you distribute your app you may either be on the sandbox or the production server. Your token will only work for the server that the app is provisioned for.

Additionally, the machine that you're sending push notifications from will need to have the correct certificate and key to interaction with the APNS servers.

One thing to watch out for is using the same Certificate Signing Request for both the development and production APNS certs, some services won't properly send if they detect the wrong certificates in a .p12 file and keychain access will export more than two items if you used the same CSR.